# VBA Closing Excel Files

Tags: excel, file, vba, ms-access

Say I have some VBA code in Access that uses excel for whatever reason.  Sometimes I have trouble closing the file properly.

The code (I think) should look somewhat like this:

```
WBO.Close savechanges:=True
Set WBO = Nothing

XLO.Application.Quit
Set XLO = Nothing

rs.Close
db.Close
```

Here XLO is an excel object, WBO is a workbook object, rs is a DAO recordset and db is a DAO database.  Even though the physical excel file closes there's still an "EXCEL.EXE" process occurring on my system, which stops me from running my program twice in a row.  Does anyone know why this happens?

**EDIT**

I took out the `rs.Close` and then `db.Close` lines since I decided to manually export the data I was using from Access to Excel (there's too many rows and columns to copy each cell over efficiently).  However, this didn't change the problem at hand.

Thank you,

Jesse Smothermon

Comment: How are you declaring XLO and how are you starting the Excel instance?

Comment: Make sure you are closing and setting to Nothing all of your object references in the exact opposite order of how you created them. Make sure you don't have any leftover references to the workbook afterwards; like straggling references to the worksheet, or any ranges.

Comment: Declaration: Set XLO = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
XLO.Application.Workbooks.Open FileName:=strfilename, UpdateLinks:=0
Set WBO = XLO.Application.ActiveWorkbook

Answer (score 3):

There isn't an actual `Excel` object. `Application` is the top-level object but that `Application` object has an `Application` property which actually points to "the creator of the specified object". So trying to quit `XLO.Application` won't do what you think it should.

Presuming that `XLO` is of type `Excel.Application` then try just `XLO.Quit` instead of `XLO.Application.Quit`

Comment: I would normally do `XLO.Quit` as well; however, technically isn't `XLO.Application.Quit` the same thing? If I execute `Debug.Print xlo Is xlo.Application`, I get `True` as a response; which means that xlo is the same object as `xlo.Application`.

Comment: The XLO is an Excel.Application, however XLO.Quit didn't seem to completely close everything.  I forgot to mention that when I get an error on the excel project (since I think some reference is still open) and I manually close the excel file I can choose to not save it.  Once I do that the program runs fine.  That makes me think that there's something wrong with the "WBO.Close savechanges:=True" line, but I'm not sure.  Thanks

Comment: @transistor1 - I believe you are correct. The `Application` property seems to be for OLE objects

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
application.displayalerts = false
WBO.save (or saveas whatever it matters)
WBO.close 
set WBO = nothing
```

I don't see a memory problem with that...

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this answer.
[It worked for me.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526228/vba-script-to-close-every-instance-of-excel-except-itself)

```
Dim sKill As String

sKill = "TASKKILL /F /IM msaccess.exe"
Shell sKill, vbHide
```

If that works, mark the answer in the link with a ^, not mine.